# How to create stacked bar chart after unstacking dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph

I'm trying to create a stacked bar chart and here is my work so far

[image: this is my work].

First off, I'm having some trouble trying to take out the "proportion" part out of the graph.
Secondly, I'm not sure if my approach dataframe manipulation wise has been the best. I've uploaded the dataframe and my code for review.
Last question I have is if I should include percentages in each stack of the graph? Would it be too crowded?

Here is my code

[image: code]

and here is what the data looks like:

[image: the dataframe]

and my output of the data manipulated and ready for graphing

[image: final data for graphing]

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Comment: Can you specify the problem? Output or dataframe or the details in the chart